# Fill a variable in C # razor through the Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, razor

I have a function that retrieves data thanks to the library SignalR (real time)

And I would like to pass this list in parameter of Url.Action to go in my controller.

```
<td>
    @{
        var Users = new List<UserConnected>();

    }

    @Html.Hidden("listUserConnected", "", new { id = "listUserConnected_" + @item.SET_NOM })
    <h3 class="text-warning"><span style="color: black" id="NombreConnection_@item.SET_NOM" onclick="chargementVuePartielleInModal('@Url.Action("DetailUsersConnected", "Parametrages", new {module = Users})')">0</span></h3>
</td>
```

......

```
chat.client.UpdateCountAccueil = function (count, listUsers) {
    //$('#@(Users)').push(listUsers);
    console.log("count accueil :" + count);
    $.each(listUsers, function (index, value) {
        console.log("listUsers : " + index + "  " + value.UserName);

    });


    $('#NombreConnection_Accueil').text(count);

}
```

How in ASP.NET (with razor) I can fill a variable thanks to a function in javascript ?

I want to fill my Users List with the list present in the js "listUsers" function. And finally sent the list Users filled in my controller through Url.Action.

I tried several techniques including :

```
$('#@(Users)').push(listUsers);
```

and

```
$.each(listUsers, function (index, value) {
    console.log("listUsers : " + index + "  " + value.UserName);
    @Users.Add(listUsers);  <-- ***listUsers not know*** 
});
```

But that does not change anything

Comment: You need to write to the html from Javascript. the razor engine is a technology for running dynamic web pages on web servers, not on the bowser. What renders on the browser is an output html from the razor engine. I answered a similar question for the select list here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537153/how-to-dynamicly-pass-data-to-select-list/56537592#56537592

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this you should do this using JavaScript and ajax request.
Because the razor page is rendered and then the server sends the html to your browser.
you can send users list using ajax

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to change the way you think of your Razor page. Basically you can keep your Razor view, but you'll need to use a client side framework like Vue, React, etc to handle all the client/ajax events better. If you want to get something running quickly you can probably still use https://knockoutjs.com/.

Check the https://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html for an example, but basically you can do your initial load from Razor into json and proceed to handle everything else with client side code.

https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/933/knockoutjs-aspnet-mvc-tutorial-beginner
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/single-page-application/overview/introduction/knockoutjs-template

You can look into React, Vue, and Angular if you want to jump into a popular solution. Angular is a bit heavier so you might want to start with Vue and React if you don't want to mess into routing and start with an app per view type of approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do via javascript. You have to use an ajax call, to retrive data from server like this:

```
function getLists(){
            $.ajax({
                url: controller/action,
                method: 'POST',
               //if you need parameters
                data: {parameter:parameter},
                //the list that you return from your controller
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#Users').push(data)
                }
            });
        }
```