# Drop Down List not working...values not adding to list from database and the value selected to display an output for display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to populate a drop down list from values obtained in a mysql database using jquery on change method using a ajax call. I am then trying to use the value in the drop down box to display data as an output on the change event but I don't know how to. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

```
      <jquery>
     $(document).ready(() => {
     window.onload = ajaxCallback;
     function ajaxCallback(data) {
      var data;
      var myOptions;
      var output;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/alldata',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: (data) => {
          //$.each(data, function (index, value) {

          var output = [];

          $.each(data, function(key, value) {

            output.push('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value.Station 
          +'</option>');
          });

          $('#dmenu').html(output.join(''));
         }
       })
      }
     });

        $('#dmenu').on('change', function() { 

        alert( this.value );
        //alert($(this).find(":selected").value());

        function stationData(data) {

        var stationName = $(this).value();
        //var stationName = $(this).find(":selected").value()

        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/alldata',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
              station:stationName
              },

        success: (data) => {
          $.each(data, function (i) {


        data[i]

        //console.log(i);

        var station_loopOp = '';

        //console.log(JSON.stringify(data[i].Station));

        station_loopOp += '<li>ID: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].ID) + '</li>' +
                     '<li>Station: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Station) + '</li>' 
                     +
                     '<li>Address: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Address) + '</li>' 
                     +
                     '<li>Sales: ' + 
                    JSON.stringify(data[i].Monthly_CStore_Sales) + '</li>' +
                     '<li>Operator: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Operator) + 
                     '</li>' +
                     '<li>Top SKU: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Top_SKU) + '</li>' 
                      +
                     '</<li>' + '<br/>';
                 });

               $('#optionT').html(station_loopOp);
            }
           });
          } 

         });
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Drop down Menu</h3>
    <select id="dmenu">
      <option selected = "selected" id="opt">Choose your station</option>
    </select>
    <div id="optionT"></div>
```

Comment: $('#dmenu').html('<option id=" ' + this.value + ' " > ' + this.value + ' </option>';

Comment: I already answered such question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537153/how-to-dynamicly-pass-data-to-select-list/56537592#56537592

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the 'changed' event won't fire ever if you only have one option in your menu. I would run the ajax call when the page is ready or off a different element or event.

Second, your `optionVal` variable is doing nothing.

You need to do something more like this in your ajax callback.

```
function ajaxCallback(data) {
  var myOptions;
  $.each(data, (i, v) = {
   var anStation = Station(v);
    myOptions.push(
      $("<option>")
        .prop('name', anStation.name)
        .prop('value', anStation.id));
  })
  $("#dmenu").append(myOptions);
}
```

Comment: ....you're a lifesaver......how can I now display information from the database once the option is selected from the drop down box?  Do I need another on change function? Please give me an example like you did above. Your help is much appreciated...

Comment: That's right, the `change` event will fire when the Station is selected from the menu. At that point your callback for the change event will get passed an `event` object that will contain a reference to the `<select>`.You can then see which option is selected, and use that to go back to the Station data you loaded (save it somewhere for later use eg. save each `anStation` into an array using your `Station.id` as the key.) Get the Station you need from the array and make another `<div>` or whatever you need to display it.

Comment: ....This is where I am lost....Can you provide an example please...(You can then see which option is selected, and use that to go back to the Station data you loaded (save it somewhere for later use eg. save each anStation into an array using your Station.id as the key.) Get the Station you need from the array and make another <div> or whatever you need to display it.)

Comment: The details of how you do that are going to depend on the rest of your code. I'd try reading the documentation that applies to what you're trying to do.