# How to populate details fields on combo box selected item change in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I have following controller class methods for get and post actions of updating a person record in my MVC application using a WCF service. There I'm using a combobox to select the ID. 
Here is my controller class methods for getting the person details.

```
public ActionResult updatePerson()
        {
            Service1Client SCOBJ = new Service1Client();
            List<Person> PeLi = SCOBJ.GetPersons().ToList();
            ViewBag.List = PeLi.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = (Convert.ToString(x.Id)),
                Text = x.FName + " " + x.LName
            });
           return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult updatePerson(Person personobj)
        {
            Service1Client SCOBJ = new Service1Client();
            SCOBJ.UpdatePerson(personobj);
            List<Person> PeLi = SCOBJ.GetPersons().ToList();
            ViewBag.List = PeLi.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = (Convert.ToString(x.Id)),
                Text = x.FName + " " + x.LName
            });
            return View();
        }
```

This is my view.

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("updatePerson")">

    ID:@Html.DropDownList("Id", new SelectList(ViewBag.List, "Value", "Text"))
    @*<input type="text" name="Id" />*@ 
    <br />
    First Name: <input type="text" name="FName" />
    <br />
    Middle Name: <input type="text" name="MName" />
    <br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="LName" />
    <br />
    Date of Birth:<input type="date" id="start" name="DOB" value="2018-07-22" min="1900-01-01" max="2000-12-31" />
    <br />
    NIC:<input type="text" name="NIC" />
    <br />
    Address:<input type="text" name="Adddress" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Insert" />

</form>
```

I want to achieve loading details to First Name Middle Name Last Name Address and NIC text fields and DOB date time input field when I change the selected value of the ID. In other word I want to load detail record to all field when i select an ID from select list for ID. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You will be needing JavaScript for the DOM manipulation. I have an answer to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537153/how-to-dynamicly-pass-data-to-select-list/56537592#56537592

Comment: @Bosco That answer is bit difficult to understand to me. Could you kindly get me something relevant to this scenario? Can't it be done without using javascript?

Comment: selected item change on its own is a Javascript event, OR you want to load an array of your whole items

Comment: @Bosco any example ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have this in your controller

```
public JsonResult GetPersonDetails(int Id){
    var person = db.Person.Where(m => m.Id == Id); //this should be accessed from the db
    return Json(person);
}
```

Then in your view, you have

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("updatePerson")">

    ID:@Html.DropDownList("Id", new SelectList(ViewBag.List, "Value", "Text"), null,  new { @id= "Id"})
    <br />
    First Name: <input type="text" name="FName" id="FName" />
    <br />
    Middle Name: <input type="text" name="MName" id="MName" />
    <br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="LName" id="LName" />
    <br />
    Date of Birth:<input type="date" id="start" name="DOB" value="2018-07-22" min="1900-01-01" max="2000-12-31" />
    <br />
    NIC:<input type="text" name="NIC" />
    <br />
    Address:<input type="text" name="Adddress" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Insert" />

</form>
```

make sure to give all inputs Id variable

Then you will have a Javascript function to call the controller

```
$("#Id").change(function(){
   var  value = $("#Id").val();
   //$.get(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
   $.get(
        "@Url.Action("GetPersonDetails")", 
        {id:value},
        function (response) {    
            $("#FName").val(response.FName);
            //assign all other variables here
        },
        "json"
   );
});
```

Comment: data: JSON.stringify line and dataType: "json" line shows a syntax error near colon. I still couldn't sort it out.

Comment: Use what I have now