# How can I send my selectlist value via asp-... tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I wrote this code:

```
@foreach (var item in vm)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image)" style="width:150px" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BrandName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>                  
                <select asp-for="Size">
                @foreach (var i in ViewBag.columnNames){
                    <option value="@i.ToString()">@i</option>
                }
                    </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductType.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="AddToCart" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Buy</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

This is only part for sure, but I have an question about sending my selected value from "select" to AddToCart method of HomeController. How can I do it with asp-route-size or asp-for tags? Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: if you want to send data to the server, then submit it as part of a form, or use AJAX

Comment: A way to do that is to use `Javascript`. You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56846620/how-to-populate-details-fields-on-combo-box-selected-item-change-in-asp-net-mvc/56853816#56853816) to know if it helps

Comment: The tag helper attributes are processed server-side. The select box value is chosen client-side, by the user, long after the server is done and has already sent the response. The only way to get something back to the server is with another request: either a form post or AJAX.

Comment: What should be this js function? I am beginner to backend sry

Comment: If it's in an asp form, with the binding set, it will just be sent to your controller by the magic of the framework. https://riptutorial.com/asp-net-core/example/8900/select-tag-helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your select items in your controller, here's a bit of code I use to create a warehouse selection pulldown:

```
public List<SelectListItem> WarehouseFilterSelectItems { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string WarehouseFilter { get; set; }

WarehouseFilterSelectItems = _context.Warehouse
                                     .Select(a => new SelectListItem
                                     {
                                         Value = a.ID.ToString(),
                                         Text = a.WarehouseName
                                     }).ToList();
```

Then in the .cshtml:

```
Warehouse Selection: <select asp-for="WarehouseFilter"
                             asp-items="@Model.WarehouseFilterSelectItems"
                             onchange="ProcessForm('filter_results', 'Inventory/jqindex/'); this.blur();">
                     <option value="0">ALL</option>
                     </select>
```

You won't need the 'onchange' event handler if you don't use javascript to post/return the data.

Comment: The way I added the "ALL" option is a little sloppy actually... you can do that in the controller, by adding to the WarehouseFilterSelectItems list.  WarehouseFilterSelectItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "ALL" });