# Couldn't Load the data on Dropdown menu using Asp.net Mvc Json

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am creating a simple inventory control system using Asp.net Mvc Json.when i am tring to load the category data.category Data is not loaded to the Dropdown menu. code which i tried so far i attached below along with the screen shot image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcQYc.jpg)

**Form design**

```
<div class="card-action">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label">Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category"
                            placeholder="Category" required>
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
getCategory();

function getCategory() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/product/Getcategory',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#category').append($("<option/>", {
                    value: data[i].id,
                    text: data[i].cat_name,
                }));
            }

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);

        }

    });  
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{

    aspoEntities db = new aspoEntities();
    // GET: /Product/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Getcategory()
    {
        using (aspoEntities db = new aspoEntities())
        {
            var category = db.categories.ToList();
            return Json(new { data = category }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error you are having?, Also what is the value of console.log(data) also look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537153/how-to-dynamicly-pass-data-to-select-list/56537592#56537592

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)  :58840/product/Getcategory:1    this is the error displayed on console

Comment: Add `[HttpGet]` to the top of the method `Getcategory`

Comment: still same error shown sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller to

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    // GET: /Product/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Getcategory()
    {
        aspoEntities db = new aspoEntities()
        var category = db.categories.ToList();

        return Json(category, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

Comment: i will email my project to you sir

Answer (score 0):

It seems your db context has been disposed before the json is being serialized.

Try to inject the db context to your controller and get rid of the using statement.

Or move your return statement outside the using block.