# Asp.net core - Populate dropdown via Ajax Call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to display my data from SQL to dropdown via ajax call, can you help me how to do it. How to select particular column name in controller.

```
//This is my Model
    public class ErrorCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int Eid { get; set; }
        public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
    }


//My dataAccessLayer

  public class ErrorDataAccessLayer
    {
        readonly string connectionString = ConnectionString.CName;

        public IEnumerable<ErrorCategory> GetAllError()
        {
            List<ErrorCategory> lstError = new List<ErrorCategory>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllErrorCategory", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    ErrorCategory error = new ErrorCategory();
                    error.Eid = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Eid"]);
                    error.ErrorDescription = rdr["ErrorDescription"].ToString();
                    lstError.Add(error);
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            return lstError;
        }
    }

//My Controller

        public IActionResult GetErrorCategory()
        {
            IEnumerable<ErrorCategory> error = errorDataAccessLayer.GetAllError();
            return new JsonResult(error);
        }
```

Finally, i want to display it in a dropdownlist in order to be dynamic but how can i do it.

Comment: Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537153/how-to-dynamicly-pass-data-to-select-list/56537592#56537592)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple demo:

1.View(Index.cshtml):

```
<select id="list" ></select>

@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "Home/GetJson",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {  
                var s = '<option value="-1">Please select one</option>';
                console.log(data);
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
                   s += '<option value="' + data[i].eid + '">' + data[i].errorDescription + '</option>';  
               }  
               $("#list").html(s);  
           }  
        })
    })
</script>
}
```

2.Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
public IActionResult GetJson()
    {
        IEnumerable<ErrorCategory> error = new List<ErrorCategory>()
        {
            new ErrorCategory(){ Eid=1,ErrorDescription="aa"},
            new ErrorCategory(){ Eid=2,ErrorDescription="bb"},
            new ErrorCategory(){ Eid=3,ErrorDescription="cc"}
        };
        return new JsonResult(error);
    }
```

3.Result:

[image]